# Optimizing code to get keys of matching values in two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

I am seeking a way to improve performance of my code: Given two dictionaries I need to find the keys of matching value pairs. So far I am iterating over both dictionaries, which will be very slow when both have up to 100000 key-value-pairs.

Given:

- keys of both dictionaries are always numeric and sorted ascending
- keys of both dictionaries refer to features of a QGIS layer I need to work with, so I really need to keep them this way
- values of both dictionaries can have any datatype but both always do have the same datatype
- values of both dictionaries are randomly filled
- values can contain duplicates which may not be removed

Does anyone have a brilliant idea how I could improve the performance? Note that also a "no, absolutely not possible" is an acceptable answer, if well founded, so I can finally stop trying and searching.

```
dict_a = {1:'abc',2:'def',3:'abc',4:'ghj',5:'klm',6:'nop',7:'def',8:'abc',9:'xyz',10:'abc'}
dict_b = {1:'abc',2:'a',3:'b',4:'xyz',5:'abc',6:'b',7:'c',8:'def',9:'d',10:'e'}
# imagine both dictionaries have up to 100000 entries...

desired_matching_dict = {1:1,1:5,2:8,3:1,3:5,7:8,8:1,8:5,9:4,10:1,10:5} # example of my desired output
matching_dict_slow = {}
matching_dict_fast = {}

# This will be very slow when having huge dictionaries...
for key_a, value_a in dict_a.items():
    for key_b, value_b in dict_b.items():
        if value_a == value_b:
            matching_dict_slow[key_a] = key_b

# Seeking an attempt to speed this up
# But getting lost...
for key, value in dict_a.items():
    if value in dict_b.items():
        if dict_a[key] == dict_b[key]:
            matching_dict_fast[key]=dict_a[key]

print('Slow method works: ' + str(desired_matching_dict == matching_dict_slow))
print('Fast method works: ' + str(desired_matching_dict == matching_dict_fast))
```

Comment: your `desired_matching_dict` have duplicate keys, which is not allowed. Value of duplicate keys will be overwritten by the second one. How would you like to handle the situation where key `1` and key `5` from `dict_b` is same as key `1` from `dict_a`?

Comment: How is it possible for you to switch keys/values? values are not unique but keys must be.

Comment: @Adamantoisetortoise good point, then its not possible, ill remove that. [at]Michael good question, I really need to keep those, as in reality they refer to features I need to work with

Comment: @MrXsquared have you tried the approach mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the competitive programming uses I've generally faced, this simple approach should work fine:

```py
dict_a = {1:'abc',2:'def',3:'abc',4:'ghj',5:'klm',6:'nop',7:'def',8:'abc',9:'xyz',10:'abc'}
dict_b = {1:'abc',2:'a',3:'b',4:'xyz',5:'abc',6:'b',7:'c',8:'def',9:'d',10:'e'}

dic2 = {}
for i in dict_b.keys():
    elem = dict_b[i]
    if dic2.get(elem, None):
        dic2[elem].append(i)
    else:
        dic2[elem] = [i]
matches = {}
for i in dict_a.keys():
    elem = dict_a[i]
    x = dic2.get(elem, None)
    if x:
        matches[i] = x 

print(matches) #prints {1: [1, 5], 2: [8], 3: [1, 5], 7: [8], 8: [1, 5], 9: [4], 10: [1, 5]}
```

You can then access your features like:

```
for k, v in matches.items():
    l = len(v) - 1
    i = 0
    for l in v:
        print('desired pair: ' + 'key (dict_a feature) = ' + str(k) + ' | value(dict_b feature) = ' + str(v[i]))
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_gen(a, b):
    for i in a:
        res = []
        for j in b:
            if a[i] == b[j]:
                res.append(j)
        if res:
            yield [(i), res]

d = dict(i for i in dict_gen(dict_a, dict_b))
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: [1, 5], 2: [8], 3: [1, 5], 7: [8], 8: [1, 5], 9: [4], 10: [1, 5]}
[Finished in 0.1s]
```